# Setup artifactory so that it's used for both caching an upstream Hadoop/HBase project & also provide build artifacts to our CI?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm getting started with Artifactory and am getting confused by all the terminology. What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/hbase.git
$ cd hbase
$ git checkout branch-1.2
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests assembly:single
```

I'd like the git clone of this upstream project to live in Artifactory along with the components that Maven is pulling down. Additionally the final product zip file that `mvn` builds, `hbase-assembly/target/hbase-1.1.6-bin.tar.gz`, I want to store that in Artifactory too so that we can use it downstream in several CI jobs.

#### Questions

- Is this approach correct?
- How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory provides you with the [Remote Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) functionality which you can also use to proxy various [VCS services](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/VCS+Repositories) although I fail to see the point in just storing a clone of a git repo in Artifactory -
The VCS remotes are mainly used for cases where you directly include source code that you don't need to influence in your own code (i.e you can't `git push` changes back into Artifactory - they will not be persisted in the upstream git repo).

If you're aiming to have your CI job clone a certain branch, run tests, build it and then deploy build artifacts back to artifactory, I would  suggest configuring your job to clone the git repo (using git not Artifactory) and then deploying the build artifacts back to Artifactory for downstream jobs to use.

Artifactory provides very extensive [integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) with popular build servers through which you can achive what's discussed here, your build artifacts should go into a [Maven](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository) repository and the downstream jobs should reference it with their own `pom` files - you can quickly setup any `Maven` client to work with Artifactory using the [Set Me Up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Artifactory#UsingArtifactory-SetMeUp) dialog.